# Howto use Rollback/Commit in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, transactions

I am trying to utilize transaction functionality in Oracle SQL for the first time and can't seem to find a good explanation.  I understand that starting a new session will begin a new transaction.  I also understand that commit/rollback is used to end it.  What I am trying to do is execute two statements and if I either of them fail, undo any changes they might have made and continue with execution.  How can I check for this condition and issue a commit or rollback accordingly?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use a PL/SQL block and write something like this:

```
begin

  statement_zero;

  savepoint my_savepoint;

  begin
    -- if either of these fail, then exception section will be executed
    statement_one;
    statement_two;
  exception
     when others then
       rollback to my_savepoint;
  end;

  statement_three;

  commit;

end;
```

See also http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/concepts/transaction.html

Comment: Ah ok, thanks, looking into blocks a bit more I discovered another issue with specific to what I'm trying to do.  I am trying to add a column to a table, set the default values of all current entries and set a trigger to update this value as needed.  Blocks only allow SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE.  Any ideas for wrapping this in a transaction?

Comment: DDL statements (CREATE, ALTER, DROP, etc.) implicitly COMMIT before and after executing.  So the actions you are referring to cannot be performed in a single transaction, and cannot be rolled back.

Comment: You can, by the way, execute DDL statements within a PL/SQL block using dynamic SQL, e.g. `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE foo ADD x NUMBER'`.  But this does not change the fact that the DDL statement does a COMMIT before and after updating the data dictionary.

Comment: thanks for the help guys, spent hours googling trying to piece this together.  Much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Along with a nice exaplample ObiWanKenobi provded a detailed explanation of Oracle transactions can be found at [Chapter 4](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/transact.htm#i6564) of Oracle Concepts guide (the link I've provided goes for 10.2, you can find the doc suitable for your version at Oracle website as well). I suggest you read this chapter to understand how Oracle handles transaction management, and the doc at whole is very good piece of information for undestanding how Oracle DB work.